# Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA (calculating mean)

Tags: r

Im studing about R. I download a dataset and import into R with this command:

```
data <- read.csv( file = "observations.csv", quote ="\"")
```

Some of the variables are: id, responsetime,errormsg, ...

In the global environment section it appears that the id is a int, errormsg a factor with 4 levels, and the response time a factor with 7040 levels. And maybe the problem is here, because response time is not a categorical variable, why the response time is being considered a factor?

But Im not understanding one thing. For example I was calculating the mean of the responsetime like this:

```
mean(data$responsetime)
```

But Im having this error:

mean(data$responsetime)

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data$responsetime) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Do you know why this is happening? The responsetime is a numerical variable so it was supposed to be possible calculate the mean..

str(data) shows:

```
   data.frame': 43000 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ callNum     : int  1 7 7 80 20 22 30 34 30 42 ...
 $ serverCode  : Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","E",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ processtime : Factor w/ 240 levels "0","1","10","100",..: 111 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ responsetime: Factor w/ 10304 levels "100","1000","10001",..: 1621 4126 8982 2743 7425 2796 3486 6212 2048 2512 ...
 $ errormsg    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Failure",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

The csv file looks like this (after exported from sql):

```
"id","callNum","serverCode","processtime","responsetime","errormsg"
"1","1","XNN","2","1204","OK"
"2","1","YNN","1","4236","OK"
```

Comment: It appears it's not numeric. What does `str(movies)` look like?

Comment: The fact that `data` is a function that returns a list of available datasets is the last problem you are encountering with `str(data)`.  It is a safer practice to name your variables something that isn't also a function name like `dataset`.  Could you please execute `dput(head(data))` and paste the result so we can get a better idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: I update the question with that. I wrote movies but it was supposed to be data, sorry.

Comment: When you read in the data, try setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. After that, investigate the `responsetime` column. I'm betting there are values that aren't numeric

Comment: Thanks, I did that but the issue continues.

Comment: I verify now and all values are numeric.

Comment: Your csv is the problem.  The quotes around the values mean that the value should be considered a string.  In your SQL query make sure to cast  `responsetime` as some sort of numeric datatype.  If you can't do that and make the file properly in the first place, you will need to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you read in the file and then set `data$responsetime <- as.numeric(data$responsetime)`.

Comment: Thanks. I did that conversion to numeric and now when try to calculate the mean like this: mean(movies$responsetime) I get NA,  and max(movies$responsetime) I get Null.

Comment: Since it's a factor right now, you have to convert to character before you convert to numeric, or you'll get the integer it uses to store values instead of the labels, i.e. the numbers you want. All together, `data$responsetime <- as.numeric(as.character(data$responsetime)) ; mean(data$responsetime, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you really! Its working now! By the way, do you know why this happened with that variable but not with "id" and "callNumb" variables? They are also numeric and in the csv they have also quotes but in R they were loadaed as numeric variables without any problem.